# Preloading images in sveltekit not working on hover

Tags: sveltekit

Why is preloading images like this:

```
<svelte:head>
    <link rel="preload" as="image" href={data.page.titleImageSrc} />
</svelte:head>

 <img src={data.page.titleImageSrc} />
```

only triggered when clicking on a link and not when hovering?
I have `<body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover"...` in my app.html and preloading the other text based data works fine on hover.

Developer tools network on hover loads the json data:
[image]

The images are only loaded after clicking the link:
[image]

Comment: Does `data-sveltekit-preload-data` work with things other than `a` tags?

Answer (score 0):

`data-sveltekit-preload-data` only concerns itself with the execution of relevant [`load` functions](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) (and implicitly [loading code](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options#data-sveltekit-preload-code)), it has nothing to do with preload links.

Those preload links are a native mechanism for starting the download of assets that will be required on the page without waiting for the code that uses the asset (e.g. an `img` or a piece of CSS) to be loaded.

They only do something, once they are inserted into the `head` which does not happen on preload of the SvelteKit data. I do not know of an existing mechanism for specifying assets to be preloaded as well.

Comment: Do you know of any workaround to preload images on hover?

Comment: You could add your own hover listener to links and generate the necessary `link` elements, but if the URLs are dynamic this might be hard to do. For static URLs you could define something like a route-to-images dictionary.